# How to install Windows in a fresh formatted hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, multi-boot, uefi, grub2

I was having problem concerned with dual boot of Windows and Ubuntu because I had Ubuntu already installed in my system. Well, there was something wrong with my **boot/efi** partition's VBR or my hard driver's MBR, which was causing problem in the installation of Windows 7. I'd posted a question about it [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524104/cant-install-windows-as-dual-boot-after-ubuntu), But that didn't help.

To fix the problem I was messing around with Gparted, boot-repair and grub.cfg and don't know what came into my mind and I deleted the **boot/efi** (500 MiB sized) fat32 partition. Which resulted into the removal of grub as well. So now there was not a a single accessible OS in my machine.

Luckily I had a Ubuntu live USB. As my **boot/efi** partition was gone I thought about starting from the very beginning. And there was not any important data in Ubuntu anyway except my highly customized Ubuntu itself. :(

So I loaded Gparted in live Ubuntu USB and deleted all my remaining ext4 and ntfs partitions. And created a giant 465 GiB ntfs partition. Now I don't have any partitions in my hard drive except that 456 GiB ntfs one. I've even removed Ubuntu option from BIOS' boot priority.

Now my question is that since there is no EFI partition in my hard drive anymore, would it cause me any [trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524104/cant-install-windows-as-dual-boot-after-ubuntu) to install Windows in my system like I had before which I mentioned in the starting of my question? I know how to install Linux after Windows. Done it couple of times, So that wouldn't be a problem. I'm just concerned about Windows' instalation in a "naked" hard drive. Would Windows' installer create a EFI partition by itself during the installation.

The reason I'm asking this question instead of trying it out myself is because I had a hunch that there was something wrong with my Windows 7 iso file so I deleted it and now I'm downloading it from another source through my, once again LIVE USB. :D This would take more than 10 hours because of low bandwidth so I though, asking about it would help me prepare myself in advance, since I've nothing to do for 10 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows does create an EFI/BIOS partition by itself. The only thing that you might/should be worried about is the MBR. Make sure to do some research about that on Microsoft's documentation on Windows. Otherwise, fixing it afterwards isn't that much of a deal and might even be doable from Ubuntu. As long as you can boot into Ubuntu before installing Windows, ofcourse.

Comment: But I formatted the whole hard drive after the mistakenly deletion of **boot/efi** fat32 partition. Now there's only this 456 Gib ntfs partition. Where do you think my MBR would be right now after the complete format? What if there's not any? I checked it before when Windows was not installing beside Ubuntu and there was no boot loader in **/dev/sda** MBR. You can check it yourself from [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8346257/).

Comment: Your question is not clear.  You mention EFI and MBR but with windows it's mutually exclusive

Comment: There are several tools that will allow you to fix the MBR (Windows even has commands for this in the command line), as well as some third party applications that will allow you to make a boot partition, EFI or BIOS.

Comment: @Ramhound EFI partition has a VBR. And at that time when I had Ubuntu installed and working, grub2 was boot manager in EFI partition's VBR, which was running grub at the startup and I mistakenly deleted it and lost my Ubuntu, and there was no boot manager in MBR at that moment as well, you can check [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8346257/).
Before deletion, the very same EFI partiton or grub I don't knpw, was causing [problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524104/cant-install-windows-as-dual-boot-after-ubuntu) to install Windows with Ubuntu as dual boot.

Comment: Now when I've deleted all partitions including the **EFI** one, my question is that would that [problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/524104/cant-install-windows-as-dual-boot-after-ubuntu) still arise?

Comment: If you're starting off with a 100% clean disk, no BIOS folder, no EFI, no nothing, you can't go wrong. As long as it's FORMATTED, otherwise your install media won't recognize the disk, nor will the system BIOS.

Comment: @RowanKaag I don't have any OS right now in my sytem. Just an Ubuntu live CD. Could you recommend any Linux tool to fix the MBR. BTW I don't think my MBR is broken. Can't you confirm it with [boot-reapir summary](http://paste.ubuntu.com/8346257/)?

Comment: what are sda4 and sda5 for?

Comment: @RowanKaag One last question. Right after the complete format of the hard disk, now I've created three partitions, 
2 ntfs : 
One for Windows and in another one I'm downoading new Windows 7 iso file plus my system drivers through Ubuntu live USB 
and an ext4: for linux, which I'll install after Windows. Now beacause these partitons are from a fresh formated hard disk, these won't cause any problem, right?

Comment: @RowanKaag sda4 and sd5? Those partition don't exist anymore but I had them for Windows installation in advance.

Comment: I highly recommend to just use a DVD player when you can to install Windows 7, unless you're sure what you're doing and using usb 2.0 OR having the correct drivers to work with Win7. This caused me a lot of headaches back in the day. No need to create a partition for that on your hard disk itself. I've seen the following errors from the log you provided:


WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

A DISK READ ERROR OCCURED, BOOTMGR IS MISSING

0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 3 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
(Do a clean instl